# Return a vector of copies of unique_ptr pointed value

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm trying to implement two methods. I have a node class which is implemented like this :

```
class Node
{
public:
    // A NodeMap is a std::map associating a node with its ID as a key, much faster for searching the Node than a simple vector
    using NodeMap = std::map<QString, std::unique_ptr<Node>>;

    Node();
    Node(const Vector3D &position);

    const Vector3D& getPosition() const;

    std::vector<Node*>& getLeaves() const;
    std::vector<Node>& getAbsoluteLeaves() const;

    bool hasChildren() const;

protected:
    Vector3D position_;
    NodeMap children_;
};
```

I have deleted all the useless things for this problem. My issue is with the methods `getLeaves` and `getAbsoluteLeaves`. The first one just returns the leaves of the node (the children without any child). The second one do the same except that is compute the absolute position. I want the Node class to keep the ownership of the children. The returned vectors are just for looking at the node values, they will not be changed.

This is my implementation of the first methods

```
std::vector<Node*>& Node::getLeaves() const
{
    std::vector<Node*> leaves;

    for (const auto &child : children_) {
        if (child.second->hasChildren()) {
            std::vector<Node*> child_children(child.second->getLeaves());
            leaves.insert(leaves.end(), child_children.begin(), child_children.end());
        } else {
           leaves.push_back(child.second.get());
        }
    }

    return leaves;
}
```

I return here a vector of pointers, I read that is was a good practice. First question, will I have to delete manualy the pointers after using them? This method made the program to crash without any messages but it compiles. Where the error can come from? How can I find it?

Here is the implementation of the second method :

```
std::vector<Node>& Node::getAbsoluteLeaves() const
{
    std::vector<Node> leaves;

    for (auto child : children_) {
        if (child.second->hasChildren()) {
            std::vector<Node> child_children = child.second->getAbsoluteLeaves();
            leaves.insert(leaves.end(), child_children.begin(), child_children.end());
        } else {
            child.second->setPosition(child.second->getPosition() + position_); // Need to edit a copy of this node, not the original one!
            leaves.push_back(child.second.get());
        }
    }

    return leaves;
}
```

This one doesn't compile and I know why, I have to make a copy of the pointed node in order to compute the absolute position but I can't do it with a `unique_ptr`. How should I solve this problem? I don't really know how I should implement this method.

Comment: Returning references to local variables is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks you fixed the first issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second function, you can copy and store the Node referred to by the unique_ptr like this:

```
leaves.push_back(*child.second); // makes a copy
leaves.back().setPosition(child.second->getPosition() + position_);
```

Of course, `Node` will need to have a copy constructor.  It's not quite clear from your question what that would look like, because `NodeMap` is not copyable (due to containing unique_ptrs).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did `leaves.push_back(&(*child.second))` in order to keep the same interface as the other method! But when having a vector of pointers like this, do I have to delete it manually?

Comment: @Wizix: Probably not--the lifetime of the nodes is managed by the original unique_ptr.